# Bordering tables with merged cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following excel table:

[Current table look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4P46.png)

I want to create a table, in the image below, with outside borders that are at a continent and country level. I have done these manually by selecting the data span for one country at a time. Is there something that I can use, like table style or something else, to not do this manually?
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xavao.png)

Comment: Is the Table columns fixed for 3 cities and 2 contiries data? If yes, you can record a macro to create a border.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to improve quality-of-life in this scenario.

1. Learn the shortcut keys to access the cell formatting dialogue window more quickly.  You can invoke the window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, and the window that comes up will include `Border` as the 4th tab down.  Once you have the `Border` tab in focus, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will apply the selected border to the `Outside` of your current cell selection.  Note that Excel will "remember" the tab you have in focus for the duration of the session, so you would only need to go to the next cell and input the two shortcut keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly apply the border again.
2. Once you have a basic cluster of cells formatted to your liking and you've determined you can simply repeat this formatting convention for the remainder of your form, you can select these cells or rows and paste or insert them in quick succession.  It should be noted that when copy & pasting cells or rows, you are "painting over" existing cells or rows, whereas when "inserting" them, you are "adding" them in, displacing the previous cells that were "in the way" (hence why, if you do the latter with a cell selection, you will need to denote the direction of displacement).
3. While perfect planning is what we all pursuit, life hardly ever follows along with our intentions.  Likely, as you are actually using the form, you'll find *that this cell doesn't quick make sense here*, or *there should be an additional box/column here*, etc.  If you want to make a change to a cluster and reapply it across the remainder but you don't want to mess with the data that's already been entered thus far, you can simply copy and paste, and immediately follow that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>.  This will copy and apply only the **formatting** of the copied cells without altering the values within.

Hope that helps?  Let me know if you've any further questions!